# Multiple Feature groups in an Overlay

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am currently using a Library called `React-Leaflet`. My objective is to create various `<FeatureGroup/>` or `<Polygons/>` within a single Overlay and toggle it's visibility accordingly.

I have currently attempted to create multiple `<FeatureGroup/>` or `<Polygon/>` within a single Overlay. I am using this Overlay to toggle the visibility of the specific Overlay Layer. I have created something similar to the following codes below.

```
<Overlay 
  name={ OverlayName }
  checked={ isLayerChecked }
  key={ index } 
>
  <FeatureGroup  color={'red'}>
    <Popup> Popup Red </Popup>
    <Tooltip> Tooltip Red </Tooltip>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
  </FeatureGroup>
  <FeatureGroup  color={'blue'}>
    <Popup> Popup Blue </Popup>
    <Tooltip> Tooltip Blue </Tooltip>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
  </FeatureGroup>
</Overlay>
```

Based on the following code above I believe that upon changed the value of 'isLayerChecked' from true to false it would hide both `<FeatureGroup/>` created. But interestingly it only hides the final `<FeatureGroup/>`. In this case it would be the Feature group that has the color 'blue'. Any advise or directions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try to surround the featureGroups with a new `<FeatureGroup>` block

Comment: @FalkeDesign I have surrounded my FeatureGroups within another `<FeatureGroup>` Block and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from comments:

Surround the FeatureGroups with a new  block

```
<Overlay 
  name={ OverlayName }
  checked={ isLayerChecked }
  key={ index } 
>
<FeatureGroup>
  <FeatureGroup  color={'red'}>
    <Popup> Popup Red </Popup>
    <Tooltip> Tooltip Red </Tooltip>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
  </FeatureGroup>
  <FeatureGroup  color={'blue'}>
    <Popup> Popup Blue </Popup>
    <Tooltip> Tooltip Blue </Tooltip>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
    <Polygon position=[array of latlng points]/>
  </FeatureGroup>
</FeatureGroup>
</Overlay>
```